# Intellij IDEA locking changeset

Tags: git, intellij-idea

How do you lock certain files or changesets in Intellij IDEA VCS (git) to prevent them from being accidentally commited?

I need it for certain property files which should have prod-settings in git, but dev-settings at local PC.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can list files which you don't want to commit in .gitignore.

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files